# CABasic animation translate not working

Tags: xcode, swift

I am using Xcode to develop an app and am trying to have a circle change it's x location. I have written the following code to no avail, the code doesn't give me an error, it simply doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. 
My code is below.

```
        func changeNotes() {
        switch notesState {
        case 1:
            let animation = CABasicAnimation()
            animation.keyPath = "transform.translate.x"
            animation.fromValue = 668
            animation.toValue = 55
            animation.duration = 0.2
            notesButton.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "transformx")

            notesState = 0
        default:
           let animation = CABasicAnimation()
           animation.keyPath = "transform.translate.x"
           animation.fromValue = 55
           animation.toValue = 668
           animation.duration = 0.2
           notesButton.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "transformx")

           notesState++
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

```
let translateX = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")  // declare it out of your function inside your view controller class just below any IBOulets you may have

translateX.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(668,notesButton.layer.position.y))
translateX.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(55,notesButton.layer.position.y))
translateX.duration = 0.2
notesButton.layer.addAnimation(translateX, forKey: "position")
```

**Edit**

No need to use case switch there. You can try it like this:

```
let translateX = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")  // declare it out of your function inside your view controller class just below any IBOulets you may have


    if notesButton.layer.position.x == 668 {
        translateX.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(668,notesButton.layer.position.y))
        translateX.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(55,notesButton.layer.position.y))
        notesButton.layer.position.x = 55
        translateX.duration = 0.2
    } else {
        translateX.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(55,notesButton.layer.position.y))
        translateX.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(668,notesButton.layer.position.y))
        notesButton.layer.position.x = 55
        translateX.duration = 0.2
    }
    notesButton.layer.addAnimation(translateX, forKey: "position")
```

Comment: It's still not working, am I doing it right? I apologize if I'm missing something obvious, I'm still fairly new to this. (Uploading this as an image because the code didn't fit) http://imgur.com/q9uMZT1

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that it's under another animation triggered by the same function change: http://imgur.com/ub0oEBn
The one on top works.

Comment: @BobJonesie you have to choose a different names to your functions. change it to func changeRadius() {...} and the other to fund changePosition() {...}

Comment: Like this: http://pastebin.com/7Hcdy5wj ? Because it's not working, the button (Which is a circle) just flies across the screen and gets stuck.

Comment: where have you declared your methods? can you show it. I told you to declare your vars outside your IBAction

Comment: You are declaring one method inside the other. move your functions and put them above your IBActions

Comment: you have to use the same key change it to .addAnimation(animation, forKey: "cornerRadius")

Comment: I apologize for being so clueless and if I'm annoying you first of all.
Second of all, I moved 
        let translateX = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
Out of the action, but now I don't know what to do with the rest of it. I apologize for my cluelessness again. I'm still learning programming.